# Best way to increase all elements in array until they reach a specific value in C

Tags: arrays, c, performance, refactoring

I am writing a function to increase the values of all elements in an array until they all reach a specified value, this value can be different for each item. This is what I have so far.

*Edit: I forgot to mention that the reason not to set it directly as in `arr[i].value = arr[i].setpoint` (as pointed out by kaylum) it is because there is a limitation where, while incrementing, the values in the array can only differ by the same unit of increment, in this case 1. So abs(arr[i].value - arr[i+1].value) <= 1. Once an element reaches the setpoint it is free of this limitation (so that the other elements can reach its setpoint)*

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned value;
    unsigned setpoint;
} ValSet;

void set_all(ValSet arr[static 1], size_t arr_size)
{
    for (size_t cnt = arr_size; cnt;)
    {
        cnt = arr_size;
        for (size_t  i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].value != arr[i].setpoint)
            {
                arr[i].value++;
            }
            else
            {
                cnt--;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ValSet arr[2] = {{0, 2}, {0, 4}};  
    set_all(arr, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

This generates the desired output so, after the call to `set_all(arr, 2)`, arr[0].value = 2 and  arr[1].value = 4, but I am not sure this is the best idea. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to increment it repeatedly rather then set it directly to the final known value in one go? `arr.value[i] = arr.setpoint[i]`?

Comment: It is part of the imposed limitation. While increasing, all values in the array can only differ by the same unit of increment. In this case 1. So abs(arr.value[i] - arr.value[i+1]) <= 1.

Comment: It would make sense to tell us that. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73331052/edit) the post to update it with that info.

Comment: And you need to be more precise. Because clearly 2 and 4 don't meet that constraint. I assume that is allowed? So your description needs to be more detailed and clear.

Comment: So... the setpoint values also must not have sequential difference more than 1, right? In other words: your example is *invalid*...

Comment: I have updated the post. Hope that's clear

Comment: Do you notice that you have an `array of structs` and NOT a `struct full of arrays`?!?! You've got the `[ ]` in the wrong location...

Comment: That looks a lot like a homework (why would you want to do it in singe steps). Usually you should not make stackoverflow solve them...

Comment: Hi, @Tenobaal I see where you are coming from. It is not homework though but a limitation of the system. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does it compile? `ValSet arr[static 1]` tells that `arr` is a non-NULL pointer to `ValSet`. It should be accessed with `arr->` syntax, not `arr`. Did you mean `arr[i].setpoint` ?

Comment: Thanks, @tstanisl, I didn't notice that. Yes, it should be arr[i].setpoint

Comment: @Blue, so maybe the function should be declared as: `void set_all(size_t arr_size, ValSet arr[static arr_size])` ?

Comment: Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica “size_t” does make sense here

Answer (score 1):

You were a bit unspecific about what you want exactly, so here are some solutions:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned value;
    unsigned setpoint;
} ValSet;

/**
 * for each element:
 * increases value by one, until value is not smaller than setpoint
 * will never decrease value
 */
void increase_all_slow(ValSet* arr, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        while (arr[i].value < arr[i].setpoint) {
            arr[i].value++;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * for each element:
 * sets value to setpoint, if value is smaller than setpoint
 * will never decrease value
 */
void increase_all(ValSet* arr, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i].value < arr[i].setpoint) {
            arr[i].value = arr[i].setpoint;
        }
    }
}
/**
 * for each element:
 * sets value to setpoint
 * decreases value if less than setpoint
 */
void set_all(ValSet* arr, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i].value = arr[i].setpoint;
    }
}
```

Your implementation has a lot of redundant checks, every element will be compared `if (arr.value[i] != arr.setpoint[i])` as long as any element is not set correctly. This will make it very slow.

I hope my code is self explanatory (I even added comments where usually you don't need them). If not, feel free to ask

Edit:

Now I know what you want. Next time tell us before:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned value;
    unsigned setpoint;
} ValSet;

/**
 * Until every element is equal (or bigger) to its corresponding setpoint.
 * Every elements value that is not, will be increased.
 */
void increase_all(ValSet* arr, int len) {
    int max_allowed = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i].value < max_allowed) {
            max_allowed = arr[i].value;
        }
    }
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        max_allowed++;
        done = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (arr[i].value < arr[i].setpoint && arr[i].value < max_allowed) {
                arr[i].value++;
                done = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wasted time on this... *sigh*... Just to point out: Could potentially save the final iteration of your `increase_all()` with `if( arr[ i ].value < arr[ i ].setpoint ) done = false;"... That increment may have meant the last horse has crossed the finish line. No need to loop through it all again... :-)